# Wp_admin shows blank after udating wp_debug in wp_config

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

// Enable Debugging

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

// Tell WordPress to log everything to /wp-content/debug.log

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

// Turn off the display of error messages on your site

```
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

// For good measure, you can also add the follow code, which will hide errors from being displayed on-screen

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

wp-admin page shows blank after adding the above content to the wp_config.php in ftp to hide the errors that appear on the site page

is there any way this problem can be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Modify `wp_config.php` file.

Open `wp-config.php` file and find the following line of code:

**Modify**

```html
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

**To**

```html
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: define('WP_DEBUG', false);

I did the above first alone and couldn't log in as well 
then I added the all of that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Please remove that line

screen @ini_set('display_errors', 0);

you just change the line

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Please try this

Comment: define('WP_DEBUG', false);

I did the above first alone and couldn't log in as well 
then I added the all of that in the question